# WhatsApp sharing message uses incorrect website title

Tags: angular, whatsapp

I have an app with a sharing ability, but when a user shares something the old and incorrect title shows up:

[image]

In the browser the website title looks like this:

[image]

Which is set in my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Moviese.at</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've removed caching and browser history on my phone but when I use the sharing function:

```js
public async shareInfo(e: Event): Promise<void> {
  e.preventDefault();
  await Share.share({
    text: `Check out this movie: ${this.movie.title}`,
    url: this.generateLink(this.movie.title),
    title: 'Check out this movie',
    dialogTitle: 'Check out this movie'
  });
}

private generateLink(title: string): string {
  title = title.replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
  return `https://www.moviese.at/movie/${title}`;
}
```

It always shows the `AngularMovieseat` which was the old title that has been updated today to `Moviese.at`.